# How to close a specified MATLAB image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

After working with some basic image processing in MATLAB for a while now, I feel a little embarrassed having to ask this simple question...  Why does the last statement of the following code fail to close a specified image?  What is the proper way to close a specified image in MATLAB?

```
clear; clc; close all; 
% 

%% Identify available webcams.  
% The MATLAB Webcam Supoort Package must be installed first.  
myWebcams = webcamlist      % Identifies available webcams.
cam = webcam(myWebcams{1})  % Identifies the current webcam.
% 

%% Acquire webcam images. 
preview(cam)                                % A preview of the img.  
img = snapshot(cam); img = rgb2gray(img);   % A single webcam img.  
imgh = imshow(img);                         % Display the img.
[imgHeight, imgWidth] = size(img)
close(imgh)
```

Using

```
close(imgh)
```

I get the following error:

```
>> close(imgh)
Error using close (line 116)
Invalid figure handle.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `imgh` is not a figure handle. It is a handle to the image object, which is inside an axes object, which is inside a figure. To close the figure use

```
>> close(imgh.Parent.Parent);
```

Or, if you have an older version of MATLAB use

```
>> close(get(get(h, 'Parent'), 'Parent'));
```

Or, even more simply, use

```
>> close all
```

Comment: Also maybe helpful: `close(gcf)` closes the current figure